# Implementing Hamed and Rao (1998) and Yue and Wang (2004) Modified Mann-Kendall test in R- Help with Correction Factor Calculation?

Tags: r, nonparametric, trend, kendall-tau, test-for-trend

I am trying to modify the code mkTrend.R from 'fume' package to implement Hamed and Rao (1998) variance correction approach.

From the code of mkTrend, the following line is very confusing (Line-29 to Line-34)

Now, Please help me with the following three questions

•   According to literature the auto correlation function is to be calculated from the ranks of observations. In the program. auto correlation is calculated as rank(lm(x ~ I(1:n))$resid) instead of simple rank(x)

```
acf(rank(lm(x ~ I(1:n))$resid), lag.max=(n-1), plot=FALSE)$acf[-1] -> ro
```

•   Similarly based on the confidence interval value from normal distribution table, only values that cross the significance bounds are considered.

```
qnorm((1+ci)/2)/sqrt(n) -> sig
rep(NA,length(ro)) -> rof
for (i in 1:(length(ro))) {
if(ro[i] > sig || ro[i] < -sig) {
rof[i] <- ro[i]
} else {
rof[i] = 0
}
}
```

•   From the literature titled 'Non stationarities in hydrologic and environmental time series' by Rao et al., 2003. (Page-34) and Basista et al., (2009). Analysis of historical changes in rainfall in the Indian Himalayas (Page-560b just before equation 9), It is mentioned that "the autocorrelation becomes insignificant after a lag of three". So first three lags are suggested. So, Can I write the Auto Correlation function for the Ranks of observations as below:

```
acf(rank(x),lag.max = 3) -> ro
```

Comment: Could you format your 3 questions as a question. For instance, already the first "question" I do not understand. Hamed and Rao describe the modified test with *"The autocorrelation between the ranks of the observations, $p_s(i)$, is first evaluated. The values of $p_s(i)$, however, must be calculated after subtracting a suitable nonparametric trend estimator (Sen, 1968; Zetterqvist, 1991)"*, which gives you this lm()$resid stuff. Are you making a statement that 1) you get that this lm() is the case 2) you do not get where this lm() comes from or 3) you don't get the use of lm() in the article?